# How can I teleport a team but have each of the players go different places?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am separating teams for a teleport system with tubes, I have 6 tubes and 2 teams of 3.

How would I separate the players from their other teammates in teleporting?

Here is a command:

```
tp @p[team=DDYellow] ~ ~ ~ 
~=cords
```

How do I separate the teams out and not group-teleport them using teams and the scoreboard command?

Comment: You don't want to use `tp`, you want to use `spreadplayers`, I think.  It's really hard to tell what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a chain of command blocks each being triggered 1 tick after the last. you will enter the command

```
/tp @p[team=Green] ~ ~ ~
```

In this you will need to replace green with whatever the team color is and then the ~ with the coordinates.

Look at the attach photo.[image]

Comment: If you use `@p`, make sure that the command blocks are closer to the players' initial position than the tubes, otherwise you will end up teleporting a player multiple times instead of everyone once.